# Connecting to an .accdb in Python and reading a table through pandas

Tags: python, ms-access, pandas, pypyodbc

I am just trying to connect to an .accdb and read in an existing table.
I am using pypypodbc to connect:

```
import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc

conn = pypyodbc.connect(
    r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
    r"Dbq=C:\Users\Public\Data.accdb;")
```

The connection seems to work and I can read in most tables using:

```
data = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM TABLE', conn)
```

However, when I try to read in a table with a column containing Double values with varying decimal points (but no nulls) I get the following:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'E-2'

How can I get this data in to pandas?

Comment: The error message is telling you that the column contains the value 'E-2' ... Is it possible that Access allows this in a Float column?

Comment: The column type is double so it shouldn't allow any text values. I also did a search for 'E-2' which doesn't seem to exist, there is however some scientific notation where a value might end in E-02. could this be part of the problem?

Comment: hmm yes that could definately be what's causing it, check out this forum thread http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/avoid-scientific-notation-in-my-number-field.3303779/

Comment: Thanks for that, it turns out that this was indeed the problem. To get around the problem I had to reduce the number of decimal places by multiplying the data by some factor , converting to an intiiger, dividing it by the same factor and converting to a double again .